# How to join two query builders and sort by first query

Tags: php, laravel

I want get user list as a query bulder & I need to sort query builder as selected 10 users first in that query builder.
For that, I got selected 10 user list as a query builder and other all user list as seperate query builder.then joined both query bulders together using unionAll(). but it is not giving the selected 10 users as first in combined query builder.

```
$topUsers = Users::topUsers();
$query = $this->otherUsers()->unionAll($topUsers);
```

So how to sort selected users first in query builder.

Thank You!

Comment: Union is just uniting your query, but it is still 1 query, therefore it won't affect the order of items. Without knowing many details I can say 2 solutions work for sure, you either go with 2 queries and combine the collections or you can use sortBy on the collection. Note that sortBy can cause performance issues in the case of bigger collections. It is also possible to order by a relation or a relation's count, but the information you provided is not enough to tell.

Comment: @Urudin $topUsers = Users::topUsers(); returns only 10 items. other query items may change time to time with new users.